# Returning Aggregate and Non aggregate values in a Group By query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

My data (sample at the end below) consists of events generated during a game played on a given date. I would like to Group the data by the first 2 columns, and for each DAY, take the MIN and MAX of the TIME column to show who was the player that scored the FIRST and LAST point for that game.  The issue is when I group the data, I can't see how to not use an aggregate function on the PLAYER column to just give the player name. The result would be one row summary for each game and look like this:

```
Location,     Date,    1st Point Time, 1st Point Player, Last Point Time, Last Point Player

---

Indoor Hall   1 Jan 22      10:13      Player 4              11:02        Player 7
```

I can do this (but its very slow) by using 5 queries:

2 queries - 1 each for the MIN and MAX time of the 'Point Scored' Event column, grouped by LOCATION and DATE

2 more queries, left join the results from the query above back to the main dataset linked on Location, Date and Time and the PLAYER column - which gives the FIRST and LAST player

1 more query to combine the results from the 2 queries in step 2.  Is there a way to aggregate the data but also to get the PLAYER name in the aggregation query or does it have to be multiple steps (which takes a LONG time to run).

The raw data sample is below.

| Location | Date | Time | Event | Player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 09:43:00 | Shot missing | Player 2 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 09:52:00 | Ball out of play | Player 5 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:12:00 | Pass | Player 3 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:13:00 | Point Scored | Player 4 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:21:00 | Foul | Player 1 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:22:00 | Point Scored | Player 3 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:24:00 | Foul | Player 2 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:30:00 | Point Scored | Player 7 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:31:00 | Shot | Player 2 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 10:52:00 | Ball out of play | Player 1 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 11:02:00 | Point Scored | Player 7 |
| Indoor Hall | 01-Jan-22 | 11:10:00 | Shot | Player 3 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Event] = "Point Scored")),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Time", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Location", "Date"}, {
    {"1st Point Time",each [Time]{0},type time},
    {"1st Point Player",each [Player]{0}},
    {"Last Point Time", each Table.Last(_)[Time],type time},
    {"Last Point Player", each Table.Last(_)[Player]}
    })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

**EDITED**

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Event] = "Point Scored")),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Time", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Location", "Date"}, {
    {"1st Point Time",each [Time]{0},type time},
    {"1st Point Player",each [Player]{0}},
    {"Last Point Time", each Table.Last(_)[Time],type time},
    {"Last Point Player", each Table.Last(_)[Player]},
    {"Matching Player", each Table.Last(_)[Player] = [Player]{0},type logical}
    })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Good simple solution. Does the sort order definitely persist once grouped?

Comment: As far as I know yes.  If not could just sort in the group

Comment: Thanks, tried both solutions and they both work.  Is it possible to refer to the new columns in the same function? Or does that require a second step. For example, could there be an additional column (true or false) if the "First Point Player" was the same as the "Last Point Player" for any given row?  I added another column in the function but this errored as it couldn't find the column reference -> {"Player Check", each if [1st Point Player] = [Last Point Player] then True else False)}

Comment: Edited.  Note the syntax and you should be able to update similar changes from here

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks again.  So the Table function refers to the grouped results and not the underlying source. That is very useful!

Comment: Just for future reference, it says here that sort is not preserved when grouping. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/common-issues#preserving-sort

Comment: Thanks. Never noticed an issue, but wonder if thats still true if you wrap it with a Table.StopFolding() or Table.Buffer() first

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("nZIxC8IwEIX/ypHZIZe2iBkdRJ0KHUuHYKsWYk6advDfmxSRIpQL3pLwQj7eu7u6FifXEg1wNNaKjQCEs3GgVLjLnc6zqFV3GuHRe9+7G4SKGpTWvLoBlGg2DKSIJ+zDG9A0Al3hGf4G7YMoGARKjTOiNN7DopY+sgTIHKak3o1QXWjo2l9IzkMURu1Ak11zggkQxTlJiKNyzgk3mwDJJOdkmwDB75b872R1S5L7ilqyfWXToEbJpQnDad4=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Location = _t, Date = _t, Time = _t, Event = _t, Player = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Location", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Event", type text}, {"Player", type text}}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Location", Text.Clean, type text}, {"Event", Text.Clean, type text}, {"Player", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Cleaned Text",{{"Location", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Event", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Player", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Trimmed Text", each [Event] = "Point Scored"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Location", "Date"}, {
        {"1st Point Time", each List.Min([Time]), type nullable time}, 
        {"1st Point Player", (x)=>  Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows",(y)=>  y[Time]=  List.Min(x[Time]))[Player]{0} , type nullable text},
        {"Last Point Time", each List.Max([Time]), type nullable time},
        {"Last Point Player", (x)=>  Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows",(y)=>  y[Time]=  List.Max(x[Time]))[Player]{0} , type nullable text}
})

in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```